# Photoshop AND virtualization questions

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I would like to know where I should ask the following question:

> *When I enable 3D acceleration in [VirtualBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) for my Windows 10 VM in my [Linux Mint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_Mint) 20 host, the window controls are not there:*
>
> [image]
>
> [image]
>
> *Is there a way to solve this, and is this a problem with Photoshop or VirtualBox?*

Comment: I would think https://superuser.com/ is the best place to ask this but do make sure to double check in their help https://superuser.com/help.

Comment: Even though my host machine is a Linux Mint machine?

Comment: Superuser is for general computing, so Linux is on topic, so is windows and VB. If you asked at the linux site, they would close it as a problem with a windows app, not with Linux.

Comment: @Mark why not write an answer from it.

Comment: [The Actual Post](https://superuser.com/questions/1571246/photoshop-window-controls-not-showing-on-windows-10-vm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Questions about Photoshop, VirtualBox, Windows and/or Linux are on-topic on https://superuser.com/, so you can post your question there.

Comment: Worth mentioning that SuperUser has [VirtualBox](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/virtualbox), [Photoshop](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/adobe-photoshop), and [Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/linux) tags.